# Undefined arguments in return with INT

Tags: java

i have the code like this when i create it like this

```
public final class PhpArray extends AbstractMap
{
    private TreeMap t;
    private HashMap m;
    
    public PhpArray() {
        this.t = new TreeMap(Request.PHP_ARRAY_KEY_COMPARATOR);
        this.m = null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object put(final Object key, final Object value) {
        if (this.m != null) {
            return this.m.put(key, value);
        }
        try {
            return this.t.put(key, value);
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e) {
            this.m = new HashMap(this.t);
            this.t = null;
            return this.m.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public Set entrySet() {
        if (this.t != null) {
            return this.t.entrySet();
        }
        return this.m.entrySet();
    }
    
    public int arraySize() {
        if (this.t == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The passed PHP \"array\" is not a sequence but a dictionary");
        }
        if (this.t.size() == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + this.t.lastKey();
    }
}
```

but when i update my project i got error in the code

`return 1 + this.t.lastKey();`

the error is an arguments + is undefined.. why like that ? and how to fix the problem ?

Comment: When do you call `arraySize()` ?

Comment: cast `this.t.lastKey()` to `int`

Answer (score 1):

[`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a generic class but in the code in your question you have used it without type parameters. This means that this line of your code:

```java
private TreeMap t;
```

is essentially this:

```java
private TreeMap<Object, Object> t;
```

In other words `t.lastKey()` returns an `Object` and the operator `+` can't be used with `Object` because an `Object` is not a number.

Perhaps you meant to call method `size()` rather than method `lastKey()`?

Perhaps this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) will help?